# Laravel-8 error with Cache::remember() function doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, laradock

My application is returning an error when storing the cache, I saw that it was saving, but it is returning this error. Can anyone say why?
Here's my function and the error:

function that returns error:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repositories\ProductFilter;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\IProductFilterRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class ProductFilterRepository implements IProductFilterRepository
{
   
    public function getProductsRecommendations($keywords)
    {
        $expiration = 10;
        $keyName = 'productsRecommended';

        return Cache::remember($keyName, $expiration, function ($keywords) {
            return  Product::query()->where(function ($productsAll) use ($keywords) {
                if ($keywords) {
                    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
                        $productsAll->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
                }
            })->where('status', 'active')->get();
        });
    }
}
```

error:

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Repositories\ProductFilter\ProductFilterRepository::App\Repositories\ProductFilter\{closure}(), 0 passed in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php on line 385 and exactly 1 expected
http://localhost:8888/recommended
```

my .env with cache settings

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_URL=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT = redis
```

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: What is this possible function `App\Repositories\ProductFilter\ProductFilterRepository::App\Repositories\ProductFilter\{closure}()` ?

Comment: This is my class. I edited my question and added the full class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a little bit, I think I know what your problem is, you are using `function ($keywords)`, but you should be using `function () use ($keywords)` because, in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f60d3da8f9ad236d339562cd89eb5dfde4eb7dce/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php#L385), you see that it is doing `$value = $callback()`, but your function is awaiting `$keywords`, if you want to share a value, you have to use `use ($keywords)` again, like your second function in the `where`.

So, it should be:

```php
return Cache::remember($keyName, $expiration, function () use ($keywords) {
```